# linux telnet server check password file

Tags: linux, password, telnet

**in linux centos 7**

> linux using telnet server
>
> What is the name of the file responsible for checking the password,
> whether it is valid or not?

Comment: No-one should be offering a telnet service in this day and age

Answer (score 1):

Any privileged (UID=0) program can read `/etc/shadow`, retrieving both the encrypted password and the encryption  algorithm for a given user.

The program uses the encryption algorithm to encrypt the password-to-be-tested. If the two encrypted passwords match, so do the two passwords, if they don't match, the passwords don't either, and no information about the actual password is leaked.

Comment: I am asking about the name of the file in which the password check code is contained.

Comment: What I want to do is modify this code

Comment: @mohammedmoha if that's for an exploit, fair enough. If it's for a production system then it's almost certainly the wrong approach

Comment: @mohammed-moha I explained in my answer. There is not ONE place passwords are checked.

Comment: Passwords are checked, as I explained above, in several programs. Offhand, there's `login`, the `PAM` infrastructure, `sudo` and `sudo`-like, and any other program that wants to. Why do you want to change the password authentication for the whole system? What change to you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

It all goes through the pam infrastructure.

Comment: give me file path

Comment: 'man pam' will give you a start. It's not one file, it's a series of them. Both config & shared libs.

Comment: Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) ;)